# ReactJs - TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, api, axios

I am trying to pull data => Crypto Exchange rates. See API spec here: https://rapidapi.com/coingecko/api/coingecko?endpoint=apiendpoint_a6893c7b-2094-4a19-9761-0c0306fe741a but getting **TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined**

Error:

```
  32 | 
  33 | return (
> 34 |   <ul>
     | ^  35 |     { this.state.rates.map(i => <li>{i.data.rates}</li>)}
  36 |   </ul>
  37 | )
```

Code:

````
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import prettyFormat from 'pretty-format';
import axios from 'axios';

class App extends React.Component {

  state = {
    rates: []
    }

  componentDidMount() {

    axios({
      "method":"GET",
      "url":"https://coingecko.p.rapidapi.com/exchange_rates",
      "headers":{
      "content-type":"application/octet-stream",
      "x-rapidapi-host":"coingecko.p.rapidapi.com",
      "x-rapidapi-key":"f4756b8409msh762478a357cd070p10685fjsnce9080fa5478"
      }
      })
      .then((response)=>{
        console.log(response)
      })
      .then(rates => this.setState({ rates}))

  }

    render() {
      console.log(prettyFormat(this.state.data))

      return (
        <ul>
          { this.state.rates.map(i => <li>{i.data.rates}</li>)}
        </ul>
      )

    }
}

export default App;```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell your processing of the response is incorrect. You chained two `then` statements. What you probably need is within the first `then` to access the rates data and set it as state:

```
  componentDidMount() {

    axios({
      "method":"GET",
      "url":"https://coingecko.p.rapidapi.com/exchange_rates",
      "headers":{
      "content-type":"application/octet-stream",
      "x-rapidapi-host":"coingecko.p.rapidapi.com",
      "x-rapidapi-key":"f4756b8409msh762478a357cd070p10685fjsnce9080fa5478"
      }
      })
      .then((response)=>{
        console.log(response)
        //response is an object with a data property that contains the rates
        const { rates } = response.data;
        this.setState({ rates }
      })
  }
```

I am not sure about the API you are using, but you should also consider taking care of a situation where response.data.rates is undefined. In the above code rates will equal to `undefined` and does not have a map property.

For example you could check if rates is an array as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Axios' response returns a Promise, but your promise which is consoling the response does not. So you're basically setting your state to be `{rates: undefined}`. That is why you're getting that error in render. I think either you can do what Gegenwind has suggested or you can resolve a promise with the response instead of just consoling it.