# TypeError: this.state.rates.map is not a function - Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am getting this error after trying to map over API response. Appreciate your help. I am able to see response in console but

is not rendering. I have managed to resolve typerror thanks to this: [ReactJs - TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59554978/reactjs-typeerror-cannot-read-property-map-of-undefined/59555784#59555784) but struggling to move forward.

Thank you.

Code below:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import prettyFormat from 'pretty-format';
import axios from 'axios';

class App extends React.Component {

  state = {
    rates: []
    }
  onSubmitExchange = this.onSubmitExchange.bind(this);


  onSubmitExchange() {
    axios({
      "method":"GET",
      "url":"https://coingecko.p.rapidapi.com/exchange_rates",
      "headers":{
      "content-type":"application/octet-stream",
      "x-rapidapi-host":"coingecko.p.rapidapi.com",
      "x-rapidapi-key":"f4756b8409msh762478a357cd070p10685fjsnce9080fa5478"
      }
      })
      .then((response)=>{
        //console.log(response)
        //response is an object with a data property that contains the rates
        const { rates } = response.data;
        this.setState({ rates })
      })

  }

    render() {
      let xrpName = (this.state.rates.xrp && this.state.rates.xrp) ? this.state.rates.xrp.name : undefined
      console.log(xrpName)
      console.log(this.state.rates)

      const items = this.state.rates.map((item) => {return <li>{ item.name }</li> });


      return (
        <div>
          <ul>
            { items }
          </ul>
          <button onClick={this.onSubmitExchange}>FIRE</button>
        </div>
      )

    }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Does the console log show that `this.state.rates` is an array?

Comment: The initial state shows 'rates' as an array; however the render method is accessing it like an object (this.state.rates.xrp instead of this.state.rates[0].xrp for example).

Comment: Seems to be only `Object` {btc: {…}, eth: {…}, ltc: {…}, bch: {…}, bnb: {…}, …}

Comment: Maybe when you set the state here `this.setState({ rates })` its changing from an array to an object.

Comment: Correct it seems that rates are getting changed to an `object`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API returns an object. You can't map over it like an array. First change

```js
state = {
   rates: []
}
```

to

```js
state = {
   rates: {}
}
```

Then use `Object.keys(rates)` to map over it.

Answer (score 0):

Sorted with this. Needed to use `Object.keys()` and then map over it as Ola mentioned.

```
      const cryptoTable = Object.entries(cryptos).map((crypto, index) => {
        return (<tr>
                  <td key={index}>{crypto[1].name}</td>
                  <td>{crypto[1].unit}</td>
                  <td>{crypto[1].value}</td>
                  <td className="tag">{crypto[1].type}</td>
               </tr>)
    })


      return (
        <div>
          <div>
              { cryptoTable }
          </div>
          <button onClick={this.onSubmitExchange}>FIRE</button>
          <button onClick={this.onFilterHandler}>Filter</button>
        </div>
      )

    }
}

export default App;
```